# Achieve a square aligned with 3 rows with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get this result with boostrap :
[image: Mockup]

The idea would be that : the black square stay as a square, even with the right "rows" being resized (on mobile for example)
And the red rows would be having the same height/width (I failed that on the image, just a quick paint mockup)

I'd love to show you some code that would be a starting point but after a few hours I'm unable to achieve this effect...

I found that template that use this kind of structure :
[Gridus](https://neuethemes.net/preview/html/gridus/html/layouts/samuel/feedback.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using flexbox as a wrapper.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.col-md-10 {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row nopadding flexbox">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="col-md-4 vc-photo photo-01"><img src="http://placehold.it/150" /></div>
  </a>
  <div class="col-md-8 nopadding">
    <div class="row nopadding">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Bla</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row nopadding">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Bla</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row nopadding">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Bla</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not well versed with flexbox, I'm going to check out the documentation and try both solutions (yours and Swellar's) to see which one will be the best for my case ! Again, thanks a lot for the time you guys took :)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this? I didn't bother with the borders, but I can put it if you like

```css
.left-div {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  float:left;
}

.right-div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 120px;
  float:left;
}
.col-xs-12{
  height: 40px;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left-div">Column 1</div>
    <div class="right-div">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">Row 1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">Row 2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">Row 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's roughly the result I got with what I tried so far, but I need the red part (column 1 on your example) to be a perfect square.. I'm not even sure that it's actually doable :( Thanks a lot for taking some of your time to help me !

Comment: That's the result I'm trying to get yes ! My only problem with it is that by "hard coding" values in pixel, I wont be able to use bootstrap's responsive system (or am I wrong ?)

Comment: It's true that using pixels can hinder responsiveness, but it really depend on the purpose of the element